# How to format the values of a model in Marionette Backbone View before rendering?

Tags: view, formatting, typescript, rendering, marionette

If you implement the `onBeforeRender` method the is no way to access the model values in order to format them temporarily

Ideally you would want to format the values just before rendering without changing the model values of course!

How to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By checking this link: http://derickbailey.github.io/backbone.marionette/docs/backbone.marionette.html

You will find that `serializeData` is being used just before rendering the template

So by overriding it, like below you can format the object values any way you want before rendering

```
serializeData():any {
        var obj = super.serializeData();

        obj.totalEnergy = Math.round(obj.totalEnergy).toFixed(0)

        return obj
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Marionette Views also have templateHelpers for this purpose. templateHelpers can be used to provide any additional data to the view apart from model. Functions can be specified to format model's data to be rendered on the view. Check out the basic example for template helpers in Marionette view's docs - http://marionettejs.com/docs/marionette.view.html#basic-example